# Rally Ruby toolkit - Pulling a driver's initiatives?

Tags: ruby, rally

I don't see in the official Rally API docs or the [readme for the gem](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby) (or even in the code, for that matter) a way to pull the children of an object from Rally.

Example: I want to pull the children `PortfolioItem/Initiatives` from the `PortfolioItem/Drivers` after I pull the Drivers from the API.

Is there a way to do this using the `RallyRestToolkitForRuby` gem?

Comment: I believe the last example on this page does exactly that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869602/rally-api-documentation-list-of-fields-for-portfolio-items